# Ошибки в функции file_get_contents или на сервере

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать плагин авторизации вконтакте, но не работает функция `file_get_contents`

Делаю на локалке. Вот сам код.

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=1&client_secret=H2Pk8htyFD8024mZaPHm&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru&code=7a6fa4dff77a228eeda56603b8f53806c883f011c40b72630bb50df056f6479e52a");
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($resp);
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=1&client_secret=H2Pk8htyFD8024mZaPHm&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru&code=7a6fa4dff77a228eeda56603b8f53806c883f011c40b72630bb50df056f6479e52a) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Q:\home\auth.vvkontakte77777.loc\www\index.php on line 13
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: попробуйте применить [urlencode()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) к вашей ссылке.

Comment: А что у Вас открывается по адресу auth.vvkontakte77777.loc ? Похоже, что запрос перенаправляется туда, но непонятно, почему.

Answer (score 1):

Для запросов по https лучше использовать curl с SSL:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
// не проверять SSL сертификат
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// не проверять Host SSL сертификата
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
// это необходимо, чтобы cURL не высылал заголовок на ожидание
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo $out;
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Спасибо, вчера уже зайнялся изучкнием curl.

Comment: с помощью curl-а ваша проблема решилась?